# SQL запрос помогите написать

Tags: mysql

1. кол-во оценок каждого студента
2. Средная оценка студента Петрова
3. Средная оценка по предмету математика по каждой группе

### [image: картинка]

Пишу так но видимо что то не правильно

1. SELECT студенты.Фамилия, COUNT(оценки.оценка) AS количество_оценок
   FROM студенты
   INNER JOIN оценки ON оценки.КодС = студенты.КодС
   GROUP BY студенты.Фамилия;
2. SELECT студенты.Фамилия, avg(оценки.оценка)AS средняя_оценка 
   FROM оценки
   INNER JOIN студенты ON студенты.КодС = оценки.КодС
   WHERE студенты.Фамилия LIKE 'Петров'